# UINavigationBar hiding animation interferes with UIScrollView contentOffset animation

Tags: ios, animation, uinavigationcontroller

In an iPhone layout, I am hiding the UINavigationBar and at the same time I want the content of the UIScrollView beneath it to stay in the same place (scroll negatively while animating the nav bar height to zero):

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
     CGFloat navBarHeight = CGRectGetHeight(weakSelf.navigationController.navigationBar.frame);
     [[weakSelf navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:NO];
     weakSelf.scrollView.bounds = CGRectOffset(weakSelf.scrollView.bounds, 0, -navBarHeight);
}];
```

The end result of the animation is ok - but during the animation, the scroll view jumps to its new position (- navbar height) and remains there until the end.

Do these two property animations interfere with each other?